# Sorting days of the week based based on current day of the week

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I'm trying to sort the days of the week using the `DayOfWeek` enum in C#, using Linq, using the following code snippet-

```
DayOfWeek currentDayOfWeek = DateTime.UtcNow.DayOfWeek;

SortedDictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan> backupSchedule = 
    new SortedDictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan>();

Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan> sortedScheduleBasedOnCurrentDayOfWeek 
    = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, TimeSpan>();

sortedScheduleBasedOnCurrentDayOfWeek = backupSchedule.OrderBy(
    backupdayandtime => (((int)backupdayandtime.Key + (int)currentDayOfWeek) % 7))
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```

If the current `DayOfWeek` is `Wednesday`, 
and the list of days in backupSchedule are

```
Friday
Thursday
Wednesday
```

I expect the outcome from above to be

```
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
```

Whereas, the above code results in

```
Thursday
Friday
Wednesday
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the sort I'd use is

```
backupSchedule
    // This lambda evaluates to `true` for e.g. Sunday through Tuesday;
    // `true > false` therefore these days will appear last
    .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key < currentDayOfWeek)
    // This then sorts each half in the normal order - not really
    // necessary if the original source is already in the normal order
    .ThenBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
```

Secondly, you can't really store a sequence in a dictionary and expect the dictionary to remember what order you put it in. It *seems to work* in this case, but there's no *guarantee* that it will.

You could not store the results in a dictionary - just store the keys in order in an array (or use directly in a `foreach`), and use the original dictionary to look up the values.

Comment: Implemented this finally. and stored the result back in an array like you suggested, after reading up a little more on how dictionaries are stored. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`((int)backupdayandtime.Key + (int)currentDayOfWeek) % 7)`

That should be a - not a +.

Say current day is Wednesday which is 3. Tuesday would then be 2, 2 - 3 = -1, -1 mod 7 is 6. Wednesday would be (3-3) mod 7 which is 0. Thursday would be (4-3) mod 7 which is 1.

With the plus you get Tuesday = 5, Wednesday = 6, Thursday = 0 etc which accounts for the ordering you ended up with.

Comment: That would give me Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday. If current day is Wednesday, I want Wednesday, Thursday, Tuesday.

Comment: Huh? No it wouldnt. Tuesday would be 6 ie the last ranked day.

Answer (score 0):

Please try and run this LINQ command.

```
sortedScheduleBasedOnCurrentDayOfWeek = backupSchedule.OrderBy(backupdayandtime => (((int)backupdayandtime.Key >= (int)currentDayOfWeek)? ((int)backupdayandtime.Key - (int)currentDayOfWeek) : (((int)backupdayandtime.Key + 7) - (int)currentDayOfWeek))).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```

Comment: does not. It yields Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday. I need to sort based on current day. i.e Wednesday, Thursday, Tuesday.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your query. Try my edited solution

Comment: This still relies on an implementation detail of the .NET generic dictionary, which could change with any framework update.